# Uncaught SyntaxError: fails on first Regex function, but not second

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

this question is *different* because the first function errors, but the other identical functions work fine.

> **Question**: Why does the first function fail, but not the second? ...in these JS `Regex` functions, from a 3rd party lib used to `parse float/ints` etc with the help of the regex function.

---

Please advise how do I troubleshoot fix this error?

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument Regex]

Comment: remove spaces between `/` and `g` in regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Syntax_error

> Syntax errors are detected while compiling or parsing source code.

Once the browser encounters a syntax error, it stops parsing the script and reports the error immediately.

You can run these two snippets in DevTools console to see it in action:

```js
const a = text => text.replace(/.*/ g)
const b = text => text.replace(/.*/ g)
// VM744:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
// Only reported the first error on line 1,
// even though the code after isn't valid JavaScript either

const a = text => text.replace(/.*/g)
const b = text => text.replace(/.*/ g)
// VM754:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
// Now that the error is fixed on line 1,
// the parser moved on to find the error on line 2 and reports it
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Artyom! any chance you can look at this `js onclick link` please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73928055/unable-to-prevent-client-side-js-href-function-click-link-from-submit-to-server